# Laravel 403 forbidden error in Ubuntu LEMP stack

Tags: laravel, nginx

I have installed laravel in the "/var/www" folder but I am getting 403 forbidden error, and folders in the "var/www" folder have a lock icon. How can i fix this problem ?

Settings like this:

```
   # Don't use them in a production server 
    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name 192.168.1.6;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more details. I can help you sort this. Like the root document in your LEMP setup and if you have set the necessary permissions on appropriate folders

Comment: Have you tried to find a problem in nginx an php-fpm logs first?

Comment: I updated my question, please check.

Answer (score 1):

If your laravel installation is under `/var/www/html` then you will need to update your nginx conf file to `root /var/www/html/public;`. Your configuration file looks ok to me except the `public` part.

Laravel's index.php is located in the public folder.

```
# Don't use them in a production server 
root /var/www/html/public; # This line.

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name 192.168.1.6;

location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

# pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
#
location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#
#       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
#       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
#       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you but i cant make it. I'm gonne install homestead

Answer (score 0):

maybe you miss .htaccess file in public folder or root folder app

Comment: .htaccess files only work with Apache servers with allowoverride all in apache2.conf. It's nginx server and has nothing to do with .htaccess files